# Migrate dataset from two MySQL tables where auto increment id key is the relation

Tags: mysql, drupal

I have two MySQL tables in my `development` database. (Some might recognize Drupal here..)

```
CREATE TABLE `node` (
 `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`nid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `vid` (`vid`),
);

CREATE TABLE `content_type_fenykep` (
  `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `field_fenykep_fid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_galeria_nid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`vid`),  KEY `nid` (`nid`),
   KEY `field_galeria_nid`    (`field_galeria_nid`)
 );

CREATE TABLE `files` (
  `fid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  `filepath` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`fid`),  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
 );
```

They are connected by the `content_type_fenykep.field_fenykep_fid` field that refers to `files.fid`.

I would like to migrate a set of records from `content_type_fenykep` with the appropriate `files` records as well to a different, let's say `production` database. My problem is that I need to change the `fid`s in every `content_type_fenykep` record because both tables have their different autoincrement states.

My first idea would be writing a program for this problem, but I am wondering if this can be solved only with MySQL or not.

Do you have any ideas how this could be achieved?

Comment: Before somebody suggests me using Drupal Import module I would like to say that this question is more about learning than simply getting this done.. :-)